# Css validator gave error for not allowed

Tags: css

> I am using validator.w3.org and got error. Why this error happened in
>   css? Anybody have suggestion to remove this error.

```
Line 1, Column 1: character "*" not allowed in prolog

Line 20, Column 2: character "m" not allowed in prolog
**m**argin: 20px 0 0 20px;

Line 31, Column 2: character "b" not allowed in prolog
**b**ackground-image: -webkit-gradient(

Line 57, Column 1: character "{" not allowed in prolog

Line 113, Column 2: character "w" not allowed in prolog
width: 90px;

Line 133, Column 2: this is not an SGML document
```

Comment: My suggestion would be to run it in CSS lint http://csslint.net/

Comment: Also use a seperate CSS file and link to it from your html/php file.

Comment: Without actually providing the CSS how can we advise?

Comment: @Aaron csslint.net is telling that all is warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

validator.w3.org is a validator for markup documents (XML, HTML, etc).

To validate CSS use https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/.